# Spinner's ArrayAdapter of Integers works: with my simple Object it "hangs"

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

If I pass my Spinner a simple array of Integers it works fine.
But I want to make an exception of the value 0 (zero).

```
        /*
         * Pass the spinner the adapter with all possible start numbers.
         */
        List<RiderStatus> RiderStatuses = DataModel.get().getRiderStatuses();

        List<Integer> tempInts = new ArrayList<Integer>(
                RiderStatuses.size() + 1);


        for (int i = 0; i < RiderStatuses.size(); i++) {
            if (i == 0 || (RiderStatuses.get(i).getStarted()
                    && !RiderStatuses.get(i).getFinished()))
                tempInts.add(new Integer(RiderStatuses.get(i).getRiderNum()));
        }

        ArrayAdapter<Integer> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(
                mCallercontext, R.layout.big_spinner, tempInts);

        /*
         * Notify observers
         */
        spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        viewHolder.spinnerStartNo = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerStartNo);
        viewHolder.spinnerStartNo.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
```

My Object is simply an Integer with the toString returning text for the zero case. I essentially replace Integer with my RiderNo in the code above. 
When I click on the spinner the screen dims and buttons become unresponsive or slow to respond.

This is the code for my Object.

```
/**
 * Class RiderNo
 * Holds an Integer, but implements toString so that an exception
 * can be made of rider 0 - the "Bandit" or unknown.
 * Use instead of Integer in tempInts.  Did not work!
 */
private class RiderNo  {
    private Integer mRiderNo;

    RiderNo(int riderNo) {
        mRiderNo = riderNo;
    }

    public String toString() {
        if( mRiderNo == 0 )
            return "Bandit";
        else
            return String.format("%d", mRiderNo);
    }

    public int getRiderNo() {
        return mRiderNo;
    }

    public void setRiderNo(int riderNo ) {
        mRiderNo = riderNo;
    }

}
```

Full disclosure: The surrounding code is quite complicated. I have a list view that is driven by a Queue (FIFO). The list view has two columns: a captured time and the Spinner in question with a list (changing subset) of numbers.

I now have more info:

This is in the Log

```
01-25 13:59:50.958 32029-32029/ca.owensoundcyling.tttimer W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
```

And there is already a question about that 
[Attempted to finish an input event but input event receiver has already been disposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588750/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two problems, at least I made two changes and it got incrementally better. After fixing the first, I got a real Exception in my code. But that probably was always a problem - just never got that far.

1. The RiderNo class needed to be public. I'm assuming the Android framework needed to access it outside of my Fragment?
2. I had to cast the item at the spinner position to an object of my class and use its accessor to get the Integer. (Pretty obvious.)